# vb.net Converting a 32-bit bitmap to 8-bit (256 colours)

Tags: vb.net, image, bitmap

I'm trying to convert a full-colour bitmap to a 256-colour bitmap in vb.net. I've tried using the Format8bppIndexed PixelFormat in creating the bitmap, but this produces a distorted 8-bit image (still recognisable as part of the proper image though).

I've done a bit of research (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17162/Fast-Color-Depth-Change-for-Bitmaps) but I'm wondering if there's a simpler approach that I'm missing? (I'm very new to vb.net)

Comment: You may want to look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761452/c-sharp-copy-an-image-into-an-8-bit-indexed-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I should put in an answer as a reference in case anyone stumbles upon this with a similar problem. The [link posted by dotNET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761452/c-sharp-copy-an-image-into-an-8-bit-indexed-image) led me to [this library](http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/1bpp.html) which solved my problem really well.